# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string[]' and 'string'

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm using ef core c# and my code is,

```
 componentName = Component_Tables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == CurrentTable).Key;
```

It gives me the following error.

"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string[]' and 'string'"

Please help

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You're trying to compare a string with an array of strings.  What are you trying to accomplish with that comparison?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `x.Value.Contains(CurrentTable)`.

Comment: Besides the comments of David & Jeroen which will solve the compilation error, you may take note that as you use `.FirstOrDefault()` will return *possible* `null` as you will get the Null Reference Exception when `.FirstOrDefault()` returns null and you try to access the `Key`. You need an `if` statement to check whether it is not returns `null` then access the `Key` or with `?.` such: `Component_Tables.FirstOrDefault(...)?.Key;`